# RDP to Linux. Set remote resolution to 1080p, and use 200%-zoom full screen?

Tags: remote-desktop

Windows (Remote Desktop Connection, 4K monitor, 200% DPI)  -> Linux (xrdp). The thing I want is that setting Linux's resolution to 1080p, and use 200% zoom, and make the RDP window full-screen.

In Remote Desktop Connection's settings, if I choose "full-screen", then Linux's screen resolution becomes 4K and everything becomes tiny (I do not want to change the DPI of the Linux desktop). If I choose 1080p, the RDP window becomes a quarter-sized window. At this point, I could click the icon on its title bar and choose 200% zoom, but it does not become full screen. Its window border makes the remote Linux screen in both horizontal/vertical scrollbars.

Is there a way to make the remote desktop 1080p, 200% zoom, and full-screen?

Comment: Have you found any solution meanwhile? I am in same situation.